# Probability distribution of $Y$ when $Y=\frac{a}{b+X}$, where $a,b>0$ and $\Pr(b+X\ne{0})=1$, $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability-distributions, self-learning

How do I solve for the probability distribution of $Y$ when $Y=\frac{a}{b+X}$, where $a,b>0$ and $\Pr(b+X\ne{0})=1$, $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$?

Comment: Did you try to compute the cdf of $Y$ ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon when I attempted $\int\mathrm{d}x\frac{a}{b+\exp{[\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}]}/\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}$ I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @GabrielRomon but I didn't treat the $b$ as a shift in the mean.  Sorry, I will recompute because there could be one there.  That may lead to a result.